# How to clear android notification from notifcation tray when app is background or killed state

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

To remove a notification from the notification tray in Android when the app is in the background or has been terminated, you can utilize a custom notification channel defined in the manifest.

Comment: below link will solve to clear the notification https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#:~:text=for%20more%20information.-,channel_id,-string

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/5038#issuecomment-1592814850